# Slick Carousel bigger width than parent element

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I 've got the following code, and when I am viewing on mobile the Slick Carousel is bigger than the parent element and I couldn't fix it with any settings. I am using Boostrap as well.

```
 <nav class="navbar  fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/assets/Intech Logo.png" alt="INTECH DYNAMICS logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="wrapper-section-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-xs-12 col-xm-12 d-flex justify-content-center imagine">
          <img class="img img-fluid floating" src="/assets/Header Image.png" alt="Careers banner image" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-xs-12 col-xm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 title">
              <h1 class="text-title">CAREERS</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 slide">
              <div class="single-item slider slide">
                <div>
                  <div class="font-italic">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo at reiciendis architecto harum nihil culpa accusantium
                    saepe ut, tempore quibusdam ex odit magnam nemo accusamus
                    numquam consequatur? Praesentium, voluptates pariatur!</div>
                  <br>

                  <span class="font-weight-bold">Darius Opro</span><span class="font-weight-normal"> Full Stack
                    Programmer</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="font-italic">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo at reiciendis architecto harum nihil culpa accusantium
                    saepe ut, tempore quibusdam ex odit magnam nemo accusamus
                    numquam consequatur? Praesentium, voluptates pariatur!</div>
                  <br>

                  <span class="font-weight-bold">Cosmin Mihalache</span><span class="font-weight-normal"> Front End
                    Developer</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.wrapper-section-1 {
  font-family: IBMPlexSans-Medum;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 54px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 8vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1c003b, #5216aa);
}
.img {
  max-width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
.imagine {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
.title {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.text-title {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

/* Slick Carousel */

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-slide {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.slick-active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: blue
}

/* Custom Arrows  */
.prev-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.next-arrow {
  right: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Floating Animation */

.floating {
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
  $(".single-item").slick({
      lazyLoad: "ondemand", // ondemand progressive anticipated
      infinite: true,
      settings: "unslick",
      prevArrow:
        '<span class="prev-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>',
      nextArrow:
        '<span class="next-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>',
    });
  });
```

I attached a photo to have a better idea of what is happening. I tried to give to the carousel padding, to set width in percentage with parent element but nothing worked. [image]

Update: Pretty sure that JS has nothing to do with it but I attached anyway

Comment: Hello, which div are you using as slick slider container, can you share the slick js code also, or it will be better if you can share a fiddle of your code.

Comment: [Link here](https://mystifying-mahavira-7b6b83.netlify.app/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing link, will check it.